# Python Flask Session in Azure Webservice produces expired Session Cookie

Tags: python, azure, flask, session, cookies

I have a Python Flask web application that uses Flask-Session for handling user sessions. The application works perfectly when run locally, but when deployed to Azure Web Service, the session cookie is not being set correctly.

Here is my Flask app configuration:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from datetime import timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DURATION'] = timedelta(days=1)
Session(app)
```

Locally, I get a valid session cookie:

```
{
    "Response-Cookies": {
        "session": {
            "httpOnly": true,
            "path": "/",
            "samesite": "None",
            "secure": true,
            "value": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

However, on Azure Web Service, the session cookie looks like this:

```
{
    "Response-Cookies": {
        "session": {
            "expires": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "path": "/",
            "value": ""
        }
    }
}
```

The Azure logs don't provide any error or relevant information regarding this issue. I've tried different configurations and also made sure that the Flask-Session package is installed in my requirements.txt file.

How can I resolve this issue and get my session cookies to work correctly on Azure Web Service?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, not sure how to close / delete the question, so here is the answer:

I encountered an issue where my Flask application was working fine locally, but not when deployed to Azure Web App. I discovered that the critical issue was with the initialization code inside the if **name** == "**main**": block. This code was executed locally, but not when running on Azure Web App.

Therefore there was no issue with flask-session, but just with my application setup.